# Summing up MySQL Boolean, convert to int

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sum up the number of boolean which is true.
If boolean is true, assign to 1.
If boolean is false, assign to 0.
Sum up values of 1 and 0 to find out how many 'true' there are.

From the code below, I get Blob output instead.

```
sum(if(pur.is_redeemed is true,1,0))
```

Please help me figure this out. Also, why do I get Blob output?

Comment: have you tried `sum(pur.is_redeemed)`?

Comment: same, I still get blob output

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to combine a `COUNT()` with the respective `WHERE`?

Comment: `DESCRIBE pur;` please

Comment: select convert(sum(if(pur.is_redeemed is true,1,0)), unsigned) from table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ColumnName is a boolean column,
this should be a pretty concise way to do it.

```
select 
sum(ColumnName>=true)
from
TableName
```

See also:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html